# Слово "безусловно" в середине предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Пишется с запятыми или без?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Он безусловно прав.* Полностью, безоговорочно. Наречие.

*Он, безусловно, прав.* Разумеется, конечно. Вводное слово.

Answer (score 3):

Синтаксическая роль [некоторых - Е.К.]слов обусловлена контекстом, и проверить, вводное ли это слово или член предложения, иногда можно путем их изъятия из состава предложения: ***без вводного слова структура предложения сохраняется, без члена предложения — распадается.*** Ср.: Цех, возможно, уже реорганизован (вводное слово можно опустить). — Цех возможно ещё реорганизовать (член предложения возможно нельзя опустить).

...**Он безусловно прав** (обстоятельственное слово, указывающее степень правоты: «вполне прав»). — **Он, безусловно, прав** (вводное слово, указывающее на отношение говорящего к высказываемой мысли: «он прав, и я в этом не сомневаюсь»). [Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

Answer (score 1):

Нужно привести всё предложение, но скорее всего слово "безусловно" будет вводным, обозначающим уверенность, значит, выделяется запятыми